# How to generate classes from schema for DataContractSerializer

Tags: datacontractserializer

Is there an equivalent tool to `xsd.exe` that will generate classes from schema, but for use with `DataContractSerializer` rather than with `XmlSerializer`?

Answer (score 0):

No- DCS doesn't support much customization of the XML format- it's intended to be faster than XmlSerializer when DCS is used on both ends of the wire. Thus, you can't take arbitrary schema and map it to a type with DCS. If you need flexibility of schema (eg, matching an existing schema), XmlSerializer is the right choice.